Python selenium, unable to open tabs after receiving the 'first' error
I am trying to run a script which is supposed to open several website to search in using selenium and chrom
For each site in the array it will open a new web tab and run a search in this site.
I either modify the web address to include the search GET request or search for the "Search" filed, enter the search text and hit "Enter" or press the correct button.
The problem I encounter is that when it fails to handle a site - it opens a new tab for the site and fails it either for these lines:
driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{site_url}', '_blank');")     driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

When this happens it keeps failing to open the rest of the sites and report:
print("Connection timed out! Skipping", site_name)

For the rest of the sites.
What I want to achieve, is that when it fails to handle a site it will skip it and continue to the next site and open a new tab for it.
I tried to add try/except blocks to handle this problem, however, it appears the connection to the browser is lost or corrupt after the first error.
I am not trying to debut what is wrong with the website I ma trying to access, I just want to script to skip it if it produced and error and continue to teh next site.
Currently it does not continue
I believe the relevant code  is this:
is_first=True
for site_key in selected_sites:
    site_info = self.sites[site_key]
    site_name, site_url = site_info["name"], site_info["url"]
    cont=True
    try:
        if is_first:
            is_first=False
            driver.get(site_url)
        else:
            driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{site_url}', '_blank');")
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    except:
        #...print some error message
#...contune program flow                



Indent is crucial in python. You need to fix the indent in your posted code because right now it's not correct. 2. You know why you don't know what's going on with your script? Because you wrapped large blocks of code in try-except. When things fail, you get a generic error, "Connection timed out! Skipping" instead of the actual error message that would help you identify and fix the problem. Remove the try-excepts and run it to see what's actually happening and try to fix it.


If you still can't find and fix the problem, you need to read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted or preferably the URL.

My indentations are correct - perhaps they were not copied to the question properly but the fact that the script is running means it is working. I tried to edit and minimize the code

We can't see the code in your IDE on your machine. All we can see is the code you posted and the indentation was not correct. Your first code block is still not correct because you have two lines on one.

We still can't run your code because you haven't provided data for the URL, name, etc. Go back and read the links I posted above and follow the instructions.
